# Visual Studio C# - method auto complete order

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, autocomplete

Visual Studio (C#) helps you when you are overriding a method, but it writes the code in a different pattern than our standard, meaning:

Auto generated code:

```
public override void foo() {

}
```

Our standard:

```
override public void foo() {

}
```

I did not find any configuration in the tools/options menu.
Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: I doubt there would be any.

Comment: Change your standard? Is there so much benefit in writing override first that you want to do it different from almost everyone else?

Comment: Resharper allows you to choose your preferred modifier order. By the existence of that feature, I intuit that it's unlikely that the feature is also built into VS without extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a work around. After you have completed your day's work, just search and replace `public override` with `override public` in entire solution and you are done.